# Is there any tool to generate a labels.rdf file?

Tags: validation, rdf

Examining the 404 errors for my website I noticed requests for a "labels.rdf" file. After some digging I think I understand what it is and want to create one for my website. But I don't really understand how to generate it. Is there any tool or a generic file that I can use?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDF is not just one format, but a collection - most likely it's expecting RDF/XML.

IMHO the esiest thing to do is create the data you need in a format called Turtle (http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/) - there's lots of tutorials online, then convert it to RDF/XML with a tool, such as rapper (http://librdf.org/raptor/).

You will need to know a bit about the RDF data model though, and what the labels.rdf file is trying to express.